# How can i access CPU register in c?

Tags: c, cpu-registers

I want to access AH register. I have already tried but it argues about `asm` identifier.

```
register int _AH asm ("AH");
```

---

Platform: Intel CPU x86, Windows 7
Trying to compile with Visual Studio 2010 (cl.exe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used something like this in my projects:

```
unsigned char foo;

__asm {
   mov foo, ah
}
```

You have more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fabdxz08.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which platform and compiler you are using.

Also be aware that the code generated from your C source code will, of course, also be using the CPU's registers.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, the asm syntax is

```
__asm assembly-instruction [ ; ]

__asm { assembly-instruction-list } [ ; ]
```

as explained here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx